# Is there a closed form for the polynomials satisfying this recurrence relation?

Tags: polynomials, recurrence-relations

Consider the recurrence relation

$$P(1)=1$$ $$P(2)=x$$ $$P(n)=x\cdot P(n-1)+P(n-2)$$

The first few polynomials are $$1,x,x^2+1,x^3+2x,x^4+3x^2+1$$

The polynomials occur in the convergents of the number with continued fraction $[x,x,x,\cdots]$

> Is there a closed form for $P(n)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let $\alpha,\beta$ be the solutions of $t^2=xt+1$.

Since
$$\alpha+\beta=x,\quad \alpha\beta=-1$$
we have
$$P(n+1)=(\alpha+\beta)P(n)-\alpha\beta P(n-1)$$

So, we get
$$P(n+1)-\alpha P(n)=\beta (P(n)-\alpha P(n-1))=\cdots =\beta^{n-1}(P(2)-\alpha P(1))$$
and
$$P(n+1)-\beta P(n)=\alpha (P(n)-\beta P(n-1))=\cdots =\alpha^{n-1}(P(2)-\beta P(1))$$

Subtracting the latter from the former gives
$$(\beta-\alpha)P(n)=\beta^{n-1}(x-\alpha)-\alpha^{n-1}(x-\beta),$$
i.e.
$$P(n)=\frac{\beta^{n-1}(x-\alpha)-\alpha^{n-1}(x-\beta)}{\beta-\alpha}$$
where
$$\alpha=\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2},\quad\beta=\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$$

Answer (score 10):

> *Is there a closed form for the polynomials satisfying this recurrence relation?*

**Hint**. The answer is yes. One may use [the characteristic equation](http://pages.pacificcoast.net/~cazelais/222/rec.pdf) (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728479/how-to-get-the-characteristic-equation-from-a-recurrence-relation-of-this-form?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91379/characteristic-equation-of-a-recurrence-relation)) to get
$$
P(n)=c_1 \left(\frac{\sqrt{x^2+4}+x}2\right)^n+c_2 \left(\frac{x-\sqrt{x^2+4}}2\right)^n.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Above and beyond what's already been written, it's worth noting that these polynomials are directly related to [Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials); in particular (assuming I have my normalization right), your $P_n(x) = i^{-n}U_n(\frac {ix}2)$, so they serve as a sort of hyperbolic analogue.  The relation can be extracted from the recurrence relation $U_{n+1}(x)=2xU_n(x)-U_{n-1}(x)$ with a bit of algebra.  This also means that there should be an explicit relation in terms of sinh and cosh, based on the relation $\sin((n+1)\theta)=U_n(\cos\theta)\sin(\theta)$.